# Compile JavaFX with Maven

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I am trying to compile a simple JavaFX project using Maven. I tried it without maven, just as a artifact in Intellij. But then it said i was missing fx deploy. with maven i can build it with the following command "mvn compile package". When i try to launch it with the command "java -jar sample.jar" i get the following error.

`Error: Could not find or load main class com.javachat.client.Main`
`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application`

What could be the problem. What am i doing wrong? Thx.

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>JavaChatGraphicalClient</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.javachat.client.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
            <classifier>linux</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
            <classifier>mac</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
            <classifier>linux</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
            <classifier>mac</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
</project>
```

Comment: You are compiling with java 7 (1.7) but using javafx 14 libraries. That must have been painful. Assuming you are using java 14, set source and target to 14. Java 7+JavaFX is not a good idea. Start with a maven jfx sample. (JavaFX versions parallel the java versions for no good reason.)

Comment: I have changed to 14 on everything now. still the same problem

Comment: JDK 1.7 comes with JavaFx binaries added, is there any special reason for using JDK 7 and JavaFX 14